# How to get the reference of a Nativescript angular modal's native view window?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to set Immersive mode only in modal page but when I do the below in `ngOnInit` of the modal component

```
Application.android.foregroundActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            // tslint:disable-next-line:no-bitwise
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
        );
```

It sets the immersive view to the app globally except the modal view. The modal view still retains the navigation bar and status bar.
Basically what I want is to get a reference to the window of the modal so that I can use it to set the fullscreen flags. I tried many things using `fragment manager` but it doesnt seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having the same problem.
Here's what I did. It is quite similar to the answer posted by aleroy.

First, I obtained a reference to the root component used in the modal view
then in:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this._modalWindow = this.root.nativeElement._dialogFragment.getDialog().getWindow();
        this._modalWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        // this._modalWindow.setStatusBarColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK)

        this._modalWindow.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        );
    }, 1);
}
```

To clear the fullscreen and hide navigation flags:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this._modalWindow.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    this._modalWindow.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-bitwise
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this same issue in my own application.  I was able to solve it using the approach below (on @nativescript/core: 7.2.1).

First, I obtained a reference to the root component used in the modal view:

*component.html*

```
<AbsoluteLayout #root>
  <!-- the rest of the modal -->
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

*component.ts*

```
export class Component {
  //...
  @ViewChild("root", { static: true }) root: ElementRef;
  //...
}
```

Second, I created a method that would attempt to hide the status bar.  This took some trial and error to get a reference to the correct native object, but the below chain was what finally worked for me:

*component.ts*

```
hideAndroidStatusBar(): void {
    if(!global.isIOS) {
        let decorView = this.root.nativeElement._dialogFragment.getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(android.view.View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

Finally, I set an interval inside the component's ngOnInit function that would try to hide the status bar until it succeeded.  This was done because the reference chain didn't resolve during initialization and I couldn't find a reliable callback to register this with.

*component.ts*

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  let hideBar = setInterval(() => {
    try {
      this.hideAndroidStatusBar();
      clearInterval(hideBar);
    } catch { }
  }, 50);
}
```

While this approach worked for me, it felt a little janky... no guarantees that it will work for anyone else.